# Logo appears only on frontpage on my Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

I have an issue with my wordpress website http://www.nalekarskou.cz/
My logo only appears on frontpage (I use the HappenStance) and I want it to be on every page and post.

It worked perfectly until today. I created my first post (so far there were only static pages on my website) and did some other minor changes today. 
Do you have any idea what can I do now?
Thanks, Klara

Comment: looks like in your header file the leading "/" to the image source was removed.

Comment: Thank you Danimal! If you have little more time, can you please tell me where can I change it back? I only change my website through worpress interface (I don´t do any coding).

Answer (score 0):

Please read this:
[Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

I do know what the problem is.

The logo is loaded like this:

```
<img class="desk" src="wp-content/themes/happenstance-premium/images/logo-big.jpg" alt="Nalekarskou.cz">
<img class="respo" src="wp-content/themes/happenstance-premium/images/logo-respo.png" alt="Nalekarskou.cz">
```

1. The first thing i notice is the img path? Most theme's use the normal mediamanager, so images are stored in `wp-content/uploads/etc`. Your logo is stored in the theme directory... strange...
2. The image path is not correct, it should include the full domain.

**Homepage logo url:**
http://www.nalekarskou.cz/wp-content/themes/happenstance-premium/images/logo-big.jpg

**Contact page logo url:**
http://www.nalekarskou.cz/**kontakt-2**/wp-content/themes/happenstance-premium/images/logo-big.jpg

You see the problem?

Ask your theme developer the best way to set the site logo, you're probably doing it wrong now.

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: Can you help me? Set my answer as accepted and then remove your question. I'm wondering if the reputation remains, thanks! :-)

Comment: @Bjorn ... If a question is removed, your reputation, for that question, is then lost.

Comment: @Craig, thanks for the info. One more question, should i encourage the OP to remove the question because it isn't within the SO guidelines? I'm unsure of this, Thanks!